# Insert data in a database table using Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ado.net

I've table named `Member_Details` in Database `Sankal_Residency`.
`Member_Details` has a total 8 Columns.
I want to collect data from 8 textboxes through asp.net webpage and store it into my table `Member_Details`

How Can I ?

And also, please let me know how to delete or update a record from an Asp.Net webpage.

How can i achieve this?

Comment: You can not. asp.net is about web pages only. It cna not deal with databases. GOod thing: you never deal with asp.net, but with the .NET framework (ans use asp.net for the front end side) so you can use ado.net. It can not render web pages, but it can connect to a database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this

Take a look at [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/dotNETvinz/archive/2009/04/30/creating-a-simple-registration-form-in-asp.net.aspx) :

**Insert :**

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

   string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["yourconnstringInWebConfig"].ConnectionString;
   SqlConnection conn = null;
   try
   {
          conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
          conn.Open();

          using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
          {
                 cmd.Conn = conn;
                 cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                 cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Member_Details(column1,column2,column3,column4,column5,column6,column7,column8) Values (@var1,@var2,@var3,@var4,@var5,@var6,@var7,@var8)";
                 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@var1", TextBox1.Text);
                 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@var2", TextBox2.Text);
                 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@var3", TextBox3.Text);
                 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@var4", TextBox4.Text);
                 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@var5", TextBox5.Text);
                 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@var6", TextBox5.Text);
                 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@var7", TextBox7.Text);
                 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@var8", TextBox8.Text);
                 int rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                 if(rowsAffected ==1)
                 {
                        //Success notification
                 }
                 else
                 {
                        //Error notification
                 }
          }
   }
   catch(Exception ex)
   {
          //log error 
          //display friendly error to user
   }
   finally
   {
          if(conn!=null)
          {
                 //cleanup connection i.e close 
          }
   }
}
```

Comment: Nice, ut it is not using ASP.NET to access the database, you know. The question is specific: you can not use ado.net, you have to use asp.net.

Comment: thanks! Okay, So this will insert a data in my database table right.but can you please tell me that how can i get connection string? I'm using Asp.net 2012 and Sql Server 2008.

Comment: guys, I'm novice to this technology so Please provide me proper solution. I've got you what you've said. thank you so much. can you please let me know how can i update and delete a particular data?

Comment: @TomTom i can't get you

Comment: @NiravDarji Considered ever reading a book or something? Now for connection strings - http://www.connectionstrings.com and some brain power will give you waht you want. That site is the ultimate ressource for all kinds of connection strings and will come in handy in the years to come for you. And yes, SOME work SOME of us expect you to do yourself.